# How to structure my stores and deal with nested data?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I feel like I am having trouble understanding/using Vuex properly. I understand the basics of it between actions, some operation to perform which may or may not call mutation methods, and mutations which directly modify the state.

I am struggling with how to structure my stores. Quick context, I’d want to be able to create, update posts as well as perform actions such as (commenting, rating, edit, etc) on a specific post.

Ex. of post structure

```
post:
    id: UUID
    content: String
    user: [Object] <- nested
    images: [[String]]
    rating_avg: Float
    rating_count: Int
    created: Datetime
```

Currently, I have a feed store which contains the posts and has an action for fetch initial posts and fetching more posts and a mutation for inserting post into the state.

Now I want to be able to comment or rate a post, but where do I do this? If I want to reuse feed store I would just need to state.posts.find(...postID...) then a mutation for commenting or rating, do I create a separate store for managing posts related actions or would I just dump this logic into the component itself which would potential separate future actions into a mix of multiple components and/or stores.

And as a side note, is it necessarily required to have a mutation for every value you want to change in a store? Seems very tedious to have a mutate for each value like rating, created, content, etc. And this seems like it would only get worse when the data is nested.

Some context for client-side usage:

It acts as a feed (list of posts) you can see basic info, title, content, view count, rating. Some quick actions you can perform is like rating, commenting.

When you rate something the backend will respond with rating_avg and rating_count which should update the rating info in the specific post that was rated.

I found that

```
  [SET_POST_RATING_AVERAGE](state, { post, rating }) {
    Vue.set(post, "rating_average", rating);
  },
```

was able to do what I wanted, but it doesn't feel correct. As the object becomes more complex the mutation will be difficult to manage.

Comment: TL:DR but if you need to copy nested object for your store, I would suggest you using lodash package (_)

Comment: well that isn't really an issue I am having trouble with and there are many ways to do it. I am just confused as to how nested obejcts should be dealt with in a Vuex setting.